# outlook-addin Determine whether the user responded to the email

Tags: outlook-addin

By monitoring to Inbox, I can monitor the MailItem information and record the information.

I have a question, how can I tell whether the user replied to the email or not, if I do not monitor   the Sent Box?

Have big god to have thought, can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME` (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040"`) and `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"`) MAPI properties using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.

You can see these properties and their values in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author, click IMessage button).